# Cannot access function in class C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that reads weather data and reports statistics back to the user. If I run everything inside of main (not using a class), I know that my program does what I need it to do. I am having a problem accessing my `display()` function by calling it with the object.

I am pretty new to all of this, so if anyone could help me understand where my error(s) are, I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Weather
{
private:
    static const int NUM_MONTHS = 3,
        DAYS_IN_MONTH = 30;

    const string name[NUM_MONTHS] = { "June", "July", "August" };
    char dayType[NUM_MONTHS][DAYS_IN_MONTH];

    int rainy;                 // Counts number of days of each type
    int cloudy;                 // during one particular month
    int sunny;
    int rainyTotal = 0;        // Counts number of days of each type
    int cloudyTotal = 0;        // during 3-month period
    int sunnyTotal = 0;
    int wettestMonth;           // Index of rainiest month
    int wettestMonthsRain = -1; // Number of rainy days in rainiest month
    int cloudiestMonth;
    int cloudiestMonthClouds = -1;
    int sunniestMonth;
    int sunniestMonthSun = -1;
public:
    void readFileData(char[][DAYS_IN_MONTH]); 
    void display();


};

Weather::Weather()
{
name: { "June", "July", "August"; }
}

void Weather::readFileData(char dayType[][DAYS_IN_MONTH])
{
    ifstream weatherData;

    //Open data file
    weatherData.open("weather.txt");
    if (!weatherData)
    {
        cout << "Could not open the data file.\n";
    }

    // Else, if file was opened correctly, read weather data into the array
    for (int month = 0; month < NUM_MONTHS; month++)
    {
        for (int day = 0; day < DAYS_IN_MONTH; day++)
            weatherData >> dayType[month][day];
    }
    // Close the data file
    weatherData.close();
}

void Weather::display()
{
    // Print report heading
    cout << "    Summer Weather Report\n\n"
        << "Month    Rainy  Cloudy  Sunny\n"
        << "_____________________________\n";

    // Accumulate and display weather statistics 
    for (int month = 0; month < NUM_MONTHS; month++)
    {
        // Reset accumulators
        rainy = cloudy = sunny = 0;

        // Accumulate weather statistics for current month 
        for (int day = 0; day < DAYS_IN_MONTH; day++)
        {
            if (dayType[month][day] == 'R')
                rainy++;
            else if (dayType[month][day] == 'C')
                cloudy++;
            else
                sunny++;
        }
        // Add monthly totals to grand totals
        rainyTotal += rainy;
        cloudyTotal += cloudy;
        sunnyTotal += sunny;

        // Determine if this month is the rainiest so far
        if (rainy > wettestMonthsRain)
        {
            wettestMonthsRain = rainy;
            wettestMonth = month;
        }
        // check if this month is the cloudiest month
        if (cloudy > cloudiestMonthClouds)
        {
            cloudiestMonthClouds = cloudy;
            cloudiestMonth = month;
        }
        //check if this month is the sunniest month
        if (sunny > sunniestMonthSun)
        {
            sunniestMonthSun = sunny;
            sunniestMonth = month;
        }
{

}
// Display this month's results 
cout << left << setw(6) << name[month]
<< right << setw(6) << rainy << setw(8) << cloudy
<< setw(7) << sunny << endl;
    }
    // Display summary data
    cout << "_____________________________\n";
    cout << "Totals" << setw(6) << rainyTotal << setw(8)
        << cloudyTotal << setw(7) << sunnyTotal << endl << endl;
    cout << "The month with the most rainy days was "
        << name[wettestMonth] << ".\n";
    cout << "The month with the most cloudy days was "
        << name[cloudiestMonth] << ".\n";
    cout << "The month with the most sunny days was "
        << name[sunniestMonth] << ".\n";
}


int main()
{
    //create object
    Weather summer;
    summer.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Editing as I figure things out. added constructor which allows my program to compile but now my totals for the months are all showing zero. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think `summer.display(char[][DAYS_IN_MONTH])` is a valid syntax?

Comment: I just cannot figure out another way to access it. Again I am sorry I am new to this. I tried calling with `summer.display();` but it said I had too few arguments.

Comment: @DieterLücking i changed a few things, I can now compile my program but all my totals are showing `0` do you see my problem?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You could research first by searching stackoverflow for "c++ weather".  This is a common assignment.

Comment: Not common with classes. My only problem now seems to be initializing my name array. It does not allow you to initialize the array in the class for some reason in VS2013. I cannot figure out a workaround

Comment: A lot of initialization can be performed outside the class, try initializing in source code.

Comment: Um, what? I don't believe you can on a private member variable as in this case..

Comment: Your constructor's initialization list is completely wrong... you want `Weather::Weather() : name({ "June", "July", "August"}) {}`

Comment: @rlbond that doesn't work either. I think this is just a VisualStudio2013 deal.

Comment: The fact that some of the months have more than 30 days is not a problem?